# Lost my device, how do I recover account on iPad that already has an account on it?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm lvl 90 but lost my Android device last week. My brother plays and is lvl 40ish, but it's his account linked to the family iPad. Is there anyway to just get rid of his and upload my village somehow through google+?

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, you won't be able to use the Google+ account linking on the iPad. However there is still a way to recover it. Prior to doing so, I would recommend first creating your own Game Center account on the iPad. This way both you and your brother can play on your own separate villages.

To get access to the account again, you may need access to an Android device. I would suggest borrowing a friend's phone for this. If the device in question is already playing Clash of Clans, you will want to ensure to link it to a different Google+ account *prior* to recovering your own; this will ensure that it can be recovered once you are done.

After that, open up the System Settings then open up Apps. Locate the Clash of Clans app, and Clear Data. This will remove the existing village from the device.

Then after opening Clash of Clans, you should see a button to sign into Google+. Sign into *your*  Google+ account to recover your village.

Now you can go into the Clash of Clans settings and choose "Link a device". Do the same on the iPad (using your own Game Center account), and follow the instructions to link your village to the iPad. If done successfully, your village should now be on the iPad and linked to your Game Center account.

Finally, you can go about restoring the existing village on the other Android device. By clearing the data again, you can then sign into the existing player's Google+ account to restore their village. Of course if they didn't play Clash of Clans originally, you can just simply clear the data to remove their access to your village.