# How can I get my Clash of Clans account back?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I had a Clash of Clans account which was 80 lvl and now my tab data has been reset. Plus before that I mistakenly deleted my Gmail and Google + Id. Is there any way to get my  account back?

Comment: Maybe you can try re-creating your gmail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/32046?hl=en:

```
  If you accidentally deleted your Google Account, you have a short amount of time to try and recover it:

    Go to our password assistance page.
    Select "I'm having other problems signing in."
    Follow the steps until you see a link to verify your identity.
    Click the link to fill out our form.
```

[**Password Assistance page**](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/)

See similar [**thread**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189625/lost-my-device-how-do-i-recover-account-on-ipad-that-already-has-an-account-on) re: restoring clash of clans account.

Comment: Thx dude I got my account back!